# Does Pubnub C++ support cipher key?

Tags: c++, pubnub

Can we use cipher key in C++?. I cannot find it in the docs or code. I use it for added security in the other SDKs.

Comment: [https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-cpp/api-reference](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-cpp/api-reference) .. I was unable to guess, which part of cipher you want to define, but from a quick look at the API (first time in my life seeing pubnub) I would say it supports everything what is needed for some reasonable security of it's operation. I think the "Set SSL Options" with flag `useSSL` is maybe close to what you are looking for?

Comment: SSL is only connection from client to PubNub. The cipher key provide client to client AES256 encryption. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time but it is almost finished and will be released very soon. I do not have an estimated release date (maybe in a week) for you so I would just subscribe to the c-core SDK github repo: https://github.com/pubnub/c-core